# sharedpreferences in phonegap

Tags: cordova, sharedpreferences, phonegap-plugins

Ian trying to use shared preferences in phoneGap 
I installed the shared preferences plugin and used the api documented in this link
http://phonegap-plugins.com/plugins/edelworksgithub/sharedpreferences

but it doesn't work or alert !!

```
function login()
{
    var mail = document.getElementById("exampleInputEmail1").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("exampleInputPassword1").value;
    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(password, "Secret Passphrase");

    sharedpreferences.getSharedPreferences(credentials, MODE_PRIVATE , alert("Success"),alert("fail") ) ;
    sharedpreferences.putString("mail", mail, successHandler, alert("error"));
    sharedpreferences.putString("pass", encrypted, successHandler, alert("error"));
    var pass_enc = sharedpreferences.getString("pass", successHandler, errorHandler);
    var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(pass_enc, "Secret Passphrase");
    var dec  = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
    alert(dec);
}
```

Comment: How doesn't it work? Any error message?

Comment: @Vash
no error messages .. it doesn't alert anything !!

Comment: plugins are async, you get the value on the successHandler

Comment: can you tell me what is : `credentials`, I thought that is supposed to be the file name where sharedpreferences are stored

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    function login()
    {
      var mail = document.getElementById("exampleInputEmail1").value;
      var password = document.getElementById("exampleInputPassword1").value;
      var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(password, "Secret Passphrase");

      localStorage.setItem("mail", mail);
      localStorage.setItem("pass", encrypted);

      var pass_enc = localStorage.getItem("pass");
      var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(pass_enc, "Secret Passphrase");
      var dec  = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
      alert(dec);
    }
```

Comment: yes! This doesn't use Shared Preferences but It worked for me to store login credentials.